# How to change mysql_fetch_assoc into mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How can i change this into mysqli?

```
// add meta_key to the query
$get_user_data = mysql_query("SELECT `meta_value`,`meta_key` FROM `table` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id", $link);

// use _assoc instead of _array, we do not need the numerical indexes.
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($get_user_data)){
  $userdata[$row['meta_key']] = $row['meta_value'];
}
```

Comment: You can start in the Manual - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.summary.php.

Answer (score -1):

Just simple changes you have to made in your code:

```
// add meta_key to the query
$get_user_data = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT `meta_value`,`meta_key` FROM `table` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id");

// use _assoc instead of _array, we don't need the numerical indexes.
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_user_data))
{
     $userdata[$row['meta_key']] = $row['meta_value'];
}
```

Comment: How can i get my data out? $userdata[2]; wokrs but not $userdata['fist_name'];

Comment: "while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($get_user_data,MYSQLI_ASSOC)", use this line instead of  "while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_user_data))"